# Why data members can be specified to be of a class type only if the class has been defined? (from the book "C++ primer")

Tags: c++, declaration, definition, incomplete-type

In the book "C++ primer" there is a section about class declarations and definitions. I don't understand everything about this sentence :

> data members can be specified to be of a class type only if the class has been defined.

I don't understand the logic behind this sentence. How do you specify a data member to be of a class type, what does this action mean?

Comment: A class type is a type represented by a `class` or `struct`, as opposed to a built-in type. The sentence means that members can be of class type only if that class has been defined, i.e., not just forward-declared. You can however have pointers or references to an incomplete type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means, for declaration of a non-static class data member of class type `T`, `T` is required to be [complete](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type#Incomplete_type).

> (In general, when the size and layout of `T` must be known.)

e.g.

```
class foo;    // forward declaration
class bar {
    foo f;    // error; foo is incomplete
};
```

On the other hand,

```
class foo {}; // definition
class bar {
    foo f;    // fine; foo is complete
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe it means that this will compile:

```
 class A
 {
 public:
     A() {/* empty */}
 };

 class B
 {
 public:
     B() {/* empty */}

 private:
     A myClassMember;  // ok
 };
```

.... but this will not:

```
 class A;  // forward declaration only!

 class B
 {
 public:
     B() {/* empty */}

 private:
     A myClassMember;   // error, class A has only been declared, not defined!
 };
```

Comment: You don't even need anything between the brackets of A.

Comment: Or B, for that matter.  Comments are always optional, but good practice in this case so that the reader doesn't think you meant to put something there but forgot.

Comment: I meant for the whole class of A, not just the ctor. For this answer to make sense, you'd need _something_ in B; specifically, a field of type A, but you don't need anything inside A. Also, I wasn't counting comments, though my original comment wasn't clear; I meant that you don't need any actual code.

Answer (score 2):

It means this specification of `member` is not valid, because `A` is declared but not defined:

```
class A;

class B {
  A member;
};
```

One reason why this isn’t allowed is because `sizeof(A)` is unknown.

This, however, is valid, because `A` is defined:

```
class A {
  int value;
};

class B {
  A member;
};
```

And this is valid even if `A` is not defined (only declared), because `member` is not of class type, but pointer type:

```
class B {
  A* member;
};
```